# DoublyLinkedList Implementation Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I thought I'd ask for a review to make sure I am headed in the right direction. Would really appreciate pointers to what I can fix/change or think of to help me improve my coding standards and be a better programmer.

```
/**
 * Doubly Linked List data structure implemented as generic to fit multiple types.
 * TODO: Implement all implemented methods.
 * 
 * @author Oskar
 * @version 0.00.00
 * @name DoublyLinkedList.java
 */
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> implements List<T>{
    private int size;               // Number of elements in the list.
    private Node<T> first = null;   // First item in the list.
    private Node<T> last = null;    // Last item in the list.

/**
 * Adds a new node entry to the front of the list.
 * 
 * @param data - data to populate the Node object with.
 */
public void addFirst(T data) {
    Node<T> newEntry = new Node<T>(data);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        newEntry.next = null; //no need since its null by default
        newEntry.prev = null; //no need since its null by default
        first = newEntry;
        last = newEntry;
    } else {
        first.prev = newEntry;
        newEntry.next = first;
        newEntry.prev = null; //no need since its null by default
        first = newEntry;
    }
    this.size++;
}

/**
 * Adds a new history entry to the end of the list.
 * 
 * @param data - data to populate the Node object with.
 */
@Override
public boolean add(T data) {
    Node<T> newEntry = new Node<T>(data);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        newEntry.next = null;
        newEntry.prev = null;
        first = newEntry;
        last = newEntry;
    } else {
        last.next = newEntry;
        newEntry.prev = last;
        newEntry.next = null;
        last = newEntry;
    }
    this.size++;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Removes the current first element of the list.
 * 
 * @return The searchTerm within the removed History object.
 */
public T removeFirst() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        //Throw exception
    }

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node<T> oldFirst = first;

        if (first.next == null) {
            first = null;
            last = null;
        } else {
            first = first.next;
            first.prev = null;
        }
        this.size--;
        return oldFirst.getContent(); // CHECK THIS HERE <------
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Removes the last element of the list.
 * 
 * @return the value from the removed item.
 */
public T remove() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        //Throw exception
    }

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node<T> oldLast = last;
        if (first.next == null) {
            first = null;
            last = null;
        } else {
            last = last.prev;
            last.next = null;
        }
        this.size--;
        return oldLast.getContent(); 
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). 
 * Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). 
 * Returns the element that was removed from the list.
 * 
 * @param index - the index of the element to be removed
 * @return the element that was removed from the list.
 */
@Override
public T remove(int index) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        //Throw exception
    }

    if(!isEmpty()) {
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (index == 0) {
                Node<T> next = x.next;
                Node<T> prev = x.prev;
                T removed = x.getContent();

                //Size of the list is 1 and the list will be empty after this element is removed.
                if (prev == null && next == null) {
                    first = null;
                    last = null;
                } else if (prev == null) { // Found element is at the first index of the list.
                    first = first.next;
                    first.prev = null;
                } else if (next == null) { // Found element is at the last index of the list.
                    last = last.prev;
                    last.next = null;
                } else {
                    prev.next = next;
                    next.prev = prev;
                }

                size--;
                return removed;
            }
            index--;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Removes the first occurrence of the specified item from the list.
 * 
 * @param o - object to be removed if present.
 * @return True if object was removed, false otherwise.
 */
@Override
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        //Throw Exception
    }

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (o.equals(x.getContent())) {
                Node<T> next = x.next;
                Node<T> prev = x.prev;

                //Size of the list is 1 and the list will be empty after this element is removed.
                if (next == null && prev == null) {
                    first = null;
                    last = null;
                } else if (prev == null) { //Found element is at the first index of the list.
                    first = first.next;
                    first.prev = null;
                } else if (next == null) { // Found element is at the last index of the list.
                    last = last.prev;
                    last.next = null;
                } else {
                    prev.next = next;
                    next.prev = prev;
                }
                this.size--;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks if the entire list is empty or not.
 * 
 * @return True if the list is empty and false if it is not.
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}

/**
 * TODO: Remove this method and override toString.
 */
public void displayList() {
    for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
        System.out.println(x.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the number of nodes within the list.
 * 
 * @return The size of the doubly linked list in terms of 
 * number of objects stored in it.
 */
@Override
public int size() {
    return this.size;
}

/**
 * Checks if object exists within the list.
 * 
 * @param object - object to look for within the list.
 * @return True if the object exists in the list.
 */
@Override
public boolean contains(Object object) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (object.equals(x.getContent())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns an new iterator capable of iterating over all the elements
 * within this list.
 * 
 * @return an iterator of the elements in this list.
 */
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
}

/**
 * Returns an iterator capable of iterating forward and backwards of 
 * the elements within the list.
 * 
 * @return a new DoublyLinkedListIterator instance.
 */
public DoublyLinkedListIterator getIterator() {
    return new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
}

public DoublyLinkedListIterator getIterator(boolean startback) {
    return new DoublyLinkedListIterator(startback);
}

/**
 * Returns an array of all the elements in this list.
 * 
 * @return an array containing all the elements of this list.
 */
@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Object[] list = new Object[this.size()];
        int i = 0;

        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            list[i] = (x.getContent());
            i++;
        }

        return list;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in
 * proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of
 * the returned array is that of the specified array.  If the list fits
 * in the specified array, it is returned therein.  Otherwise, a new
 * array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and
 * the size of this list.
 * 
 * @param T - the runtime type of the array to contain the collection
 * @param a - the array into which the elements of this list are to be stored, 
 *              if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime 
 *              type is allocated for this purpose.
 * @return  an array containing the elements of this list.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "hiding", "unchecked" })
@Override
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) { 
    //TODO: Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

/**
 * Removes all the elements from the list.
 * The list will be empty after this call returns.
 */
@Override
public void clear() {
    first = null;
    last  = null;
    size = 0;
}

/**
 * Returns the element at the specified index.
 * 
 * @param index - position of the item to return.
 * @return the element at the specified position in this list.
 */
@Override
public T get(int index) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return x.getContent();
            }
            index--;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Replaces the element at the given index.
 * 
 * @param index - position of the element to replace.
 * @param element - the element to replace the old element with.
 * @return the old element at the specified position.
 */
@Override
public T set(int index, T element) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (index == 0) {
                T oldElement = x.getContent();
                x.setContent(element);
                return oldElement;
            }
            index--;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the specified index and pushes
 * old elements position forward by one.
 * 
 * @param index - position element should be inserted at.
 * @param element - element to be inserted.
 */
@Override
public void add(int index, T element) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

/**
 * Node object used by this list.
 *  
 * @author Oskar
 * @version 0.00.00
 */
private static class Node<T> {
    private T content;
    private Node<T> next;
    private Node<T> prev;

    /**
     * 
     * @param searchTerm
     */
    public Node(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param content
     */
    public void setContent(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * Iterator class for the doubly linked list capable of iterating
 * forwards and backwards.
 * 
 * @author Oskar
 * @version 0.00.00
 */
public class DoublyLinkedListIterator implements Iterator<T> {

    private Node<T> iteratorNode;
    public int index;

    /**
     * Initializes a DoublyLinkedListIterator with the default value of 
     * iteratorNode starting from the start of the list.
     */
    public DoublyLinkedListIterator() {
        this.iteratorNode = first;
        this.index = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes a DoublyLinkedListIterator with the option of choosing
     * if iteratorNode should start at the first element or last of the list.
     * 
     * @param setToLast - Set the iteratorNode to the last item of the DoublyLinkedList
     */
    public DoublyLinkedListIterator(boolean setToLast) {
        if (setToLast) {
            this.iteratorNode = last;
            this.index = size();
        } else {
            this.iteratorNode = first;
            this.index = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the iteratorNode to the DoublyLinkedList boundy elements last or first.
     * 
     * @param setToLast - Set the iteratorNode to the last item of the DoublyLinkedList
     */
    public void update(boolean setToLast) {
        if (setToLast) {
            this.iteratorNode = last;
            this.index = size();
        } else {
            this.iteratorNode = first;
            this.index = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the list contains more items forward in the list.
     * 
     * @return True if there is more elements forwards in the list.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the list contains more items backwards in the list.
     * 
     * @return True if there is more elements backwards in the list.
     */
    public boolean hasPrev() {
        return index > 1;
    }

    /**
     * Traverses forward in the list then returns the element at the current
     * position in the list. 
     * 
     * @return next element in the iteration.
     */
    @Override
    public T next() {
        T current = iteratorNode.getContent();

        if (hasNext()) {
            iteratorNode = iteratorNode.next;
        }

        index++;
        return current;
    }

    /**
     * Traverses backwards in the list then returns the element at the current 
     * position in the list.
     * 
     * @return previous element in the iteration.
     */
    public T prev() {
        T current = iteratorNode.getContent();

        if (hasPrev()) {
            iteratorNode = iteratorNode.prev;
        }

        index--;
        return current;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current element in the iteration without traversing the list.
     * 
     * @return current element in the iteration.
     */
    public T current() {
        return iteratorNode.getContent();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void addFirst(T data) {
    Node<T> newEntry = new Node<T>(data);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        newEntry.next = null; //no need since its null by default
        newEntry.prev = null; //no need since its null by default
        first = newEntry;
        last = newEntry;
    } else {
        first.prev = newEntry;
        newEntry.next = first;
        newEntry.prev = null; //no need since its null by default
        first = newEntry;
    }
    this.size++;
}
```

You can move code out of the individual cases if they're shared:

```
public void addFirst(T data) {
    Node<T> newEntry = new Node<T>(data);
    newEntry.prev = null; //no need since its null by default

    if (isEmpty()) {
        newEntry.next = null; //no need since its null by default
        last = newEntry;
    } else {
        first.prev = newEntry;
        newEntry.next = first;
    }

    first = newEntry;
    this.size++;
}
```

You could even remove the "no need since null by default" lines. I'd remove them since your nodes are tightly coupled with the list itself - it's not like you're going to use different nodes all of a sudden.

```
if (isEmpty()) {
    //Throw exception
}

if (!isEmpty()) {
```

If you're going to throw an exception, then there is no need for the second if. If you're not going to throw an exception, you could at the least just turn it into an else.

```
    Node<T> oldFirst = first;

    if (first.next == null) {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    } else {
        first = first.next;
        first.prev = null;
    }
```

Combine redundant paths...

```
    Node<T> oldFirst = first;

    first = first.next;

    if (first == null) {
        last = null;
    } else {
        first.prev = null;
    }
```

You should look for this pattern throughout your code.

Comment: Good points, thanks. I guess it is really easy to get into the pattern to repeat yourself once you started out doing it. I will try to keep track of this in the future!

Comment: @pigmgd one more thing by the way, with "remove the "no need since null by default" lines." do you mean remove the comments or the entire statement. Im guessing you mean the statement but i want to make sure.

Comment: The entire statement, of course.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I see is a lot of this pattern:

```
public T method() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        //Throw exception
    }

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        //Do stuff
    }
    return null;
}
```

The first `if` checks `isEmpty` and throws an exception, which leaves the method. The second `if` check is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

When implementing the standard collection classes take a look at [java.util.AbstractSequentialList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html). It implements everything based on the `listIterator(int)` and `size()` methods. You only need to override the others when you can implement them much more efficiently than what can be done using those two.

Comment: Yeah... that's the way to go. Provide an implementation for those methods and voila, you have a doubly linked list.

Comment: Oh so basically i could change my current class to implement AbstractSequentialList instead of List to make my class just contain me most important methods instead of cluttering the class with all the methods from the Collection class?

Comment: @BrokenProgrammer it'll need to `extends AbstractSequentialList`, but that's it exactly.

Comment: @ratchetfreak my bad i think i misread AbstractSequentialList as an Interface. Also do you have any tips of how to learn more about classes like this? Would be nice to get into the habit of extending / implementing the right things from the start.

Comment: @BrokenProgrammer I learned about them by looking through the javadocs. On [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) you can see that it extends `AbstractSequentialList`, `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList`. [The page for `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) also lists which classes implement it which include `AbstractList` and `AbstractSequentialList`. When you see an a class with abstract there is a high chance that it's has a general purpose implementation of some of the methods.

Comment: @ratchetfreak By the way, quick question while I'm at it. Is it a good idea while implementing a method like add(int index, T element) to re-use older methods like the ones I've implemented addFirst & add for the cases that adds an element to the front respectively the back of the list?

Answer (score 2):

The great advantage of a double linked list is when used in a cyclic fashion. The list head is "just" an element in the list. This style of implementation may be found (historically) in Simula. See [ref/1](https://books.google.se/books?id=l2D2BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=simset%20simula&source=bl&ots=BphRRRmfa5&sig=YWbt5P-ZxX0mLUCxlyQ9-EUmAjI&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAlZqX9K_QAhVFkCwKHeRKAesQ6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=simset%20simula&f=false) and [ref/2](http://staff.um.edu.mt/jskl1/talk.html).

With this approach much of the code, e.g. conditional blocks, will simply vanish.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more, I am not quite sure i understand. You mean that the last element will point back to the head so all elements are connected ?